# Sum IIF query error - subqueries cannot be used

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to get this query to work and is throwing up the error that subqueries cannot be used in the expression...

```
SELECT qrySrcReq.MDC_Office,
Count(qrySrcReq.ReqNumKey) AS Ct_ReqNRs,
Count(IIf([3PL]="yes",0)) AS Ct_3PLReqNrs,
Count(IIf([3PL] Is Null,0)) AS Ct_OtherReqNrs,
Sum(IIf([3PL]="yes",[BO_Qty],0)) AS Sum_3PLBOs,
Sum(qrySrcReq.BO_Qty) AS BO_Qty,
IIf([qrySrcReq]![Priority] Like "04*","3PL","Tactical") AS Strategy
FROM qrySrcReq
WHERE (((qrySrcReq.Priority) Like "04*") AND ((qrySrcReq.[3PL Status])="C")) OR (((qrySrcReq.Priority) Is Not Null) AND ((qrySrcReq.[3PL Status]) Is Null Or (qrySrcReq.[3PL Status])=""))
GROUP BY qrySrcReq.MDC_Office,
IIf([qrySrcReq]![Priority] Like "04*","3PL","Tactical");
```

The line that is throwing the error is: 
Sum(IIf([3PL]="yes",[BO_Qty],0)) AS Sum_3PLBOs

Is there another way to right this to get it to work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Sum(qrySrcReq.BO_Qty) AS BO_Qty
```

to

```
Sum(qrySrcReq.BO_Qty) AS Sum_BO_Qty
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.  Never would have tried that.  I kept changing the Sum(IIf([3PL]="yes... statement.

Comment: It tried to use `BO_Qty` calculated field instead of field from the query with the same name.